# No connection via 3G modem

Tags: ubuntu, modem, 3g

I have an ERRCISON F5521gw internal 3G modem which I have been using for years with many versions of Ubuntu, but since I have installed Ubuntu Mate 22.04 it stopped working. Here is output of `lsusb` showing that the hardware detected on the usb bus:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bdb:190d Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV F5521gw
```

but there is no broadband connection available in network manager and I can't find any `/dev` file for this device.

Does anyone have the same experience and get it to work?

Comment: ah, maybe the firmware package got renamed?

Comment: What does it mean?